# Download all lines from CSV using gsutil

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm trying to figure out a way to download multiple files from a single bucket.
Assume I have a bucket with hundreds of files and I want to download 65 of those files.

I can obviously go to the console and download each file I need individually, but this is not very efficient.

One other option would be to download an entire folder using

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket/folder [destination folder]
```

However, that will download ALL files, which isn't convenient either.

Can I somehow include all the filenames I want in a CSV and have gsutil iterate that CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a CSV file directly, but you can pipe a list of urls into gsutil:

list_of_urls > gsutil -m cp -I ./download_dir

Perhaps that is good enough.